# C# download code behind inspect element

Tags: c#, html, download, element, inspect

Is there any way to download the code that is shown in the inspect element? It's different than the code in the page source and I need it.

Comment: Nope, unless you've configured the webpage for it.  IIS specifically blocks downloading *.cs files.

Comment: What do you mean by "the code that is shown in the inspect element"?  If you're inspecting the element in your browser then you *have* "downloaded" that code.  The browser wouldn't be able to see it otherwise.  Can you elaborate with an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: Are you talking about when you right click the page in your browser and click "Inspect", and you want to copy the html markup? In Chrome, you could right click the `<body>` element in the inspector, hover over "Copy", and select one of the options.

Comment: How are you inspecting the elements? And are you referring to the HTML code?

Comment: Hi Jason, yes, I need to write a function that downloads the same code that I see when i'm clicking on a page > inspect element. i dont need the page source code.

Comment: @OferGozlan Not sure if you have a solution yet, but look into PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

While you can copy the actual rendered markup that is generated from the page (via the Developer Tools) quite easily, it's only going to be the content *after* it si been rendered and processed by the server.

You aren't going to be able to access the raw code-behind files (e.g. `*.cshtml`, `*.cs`, `*.aspx.cs`) unless the server is explicitly configured to enable them to be accessed, which is turned off by default (with good reason).

Your best option might be to simply ask the developers of the site for the files themselves or how they accomplished something that you are trying to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the HTML code for a given web page. It should be noted that javascript wont be executed. this is just a plain text representation of the webpage.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var contents = client.DownloadString("http://www.yahoo.com");
            Console.WriteLine(contents);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need the page source. I need the code that I see when i'm clicking inspect element. the code is different because there is a lot of javascript in the page.